# Изменить относительный путь для файлов на странице, отображаемой по «виртуальному» адресу

Tags: nginx

Есть сайт `site.ru`, и скрипт `index.php?page=videos`, но хочется, чтобы открывалось это по урлу `site.ru/myvideo/`

Но в таком случае все `CSS/JS`, указанные не абсолютным путем, а относительным (`script src="scripts/jquery.js"`), при открытии папки `site.ru/myvideo/`, не будут отображаться.

Как же все таки настроить `nginx` для такой ситуации?

Понял, что необходимо сделать блок `location`, и в нем задать `try_files`, но как точнее?

Comment: @bo0l, А что мешает указывать абслютные пути?

Comment: @dekameron, запрещено модифицировать файлы, где как раз прописаны эти пути, такое вот задание у меня, нужно именно с помощью конфигурации nginx прописать.

Comment: Думаю, вам надо глянуть [комментарий к этому ответу](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/5217#5235)

Answer (score 1):

можно использовать, например, такую конструкцию:

```
location ~ ^/videos/?$ {
  alias /путь/к/корню/сайта;
  try_files /index.php?page=videos =404;
}
location ~ ^/videos/(.+)$ {
  alias /путь/к/корню/сайта;
  try_files /$1 =404;
}
```

- благодаря директиве `alias` путь в этих *location-ах* будет «вычисляться» от корня сайта, а не от несуществующего «каталога» `videos`.
- если запрашивается `/videos` или `/videos/`, то будет предпринята попытка «вызвать» `/путь/к/корню/сайта/index.php` с параметром `?page=videos`
- если же запрашивается, например, `/videos/каталог/файл`, будет опробовано получение файла `/путь/к/корню/сайта/каталог/файл`
- в обоих *location-ах*, на всякий случай, если предыдущая попытка окажется неудачной, указано вернуть *ошибку 404*

Comment: так при запросе любого несуществующего статического файла будет дёргаться `/index.php?page=videos`, что, по-моему, не правильно. Надо писать два правила: полное совпадение url – скрипт. Совпадение только начала – alias + try_files

Comment: @Sergiks, да, про это я не подумал. спасибо, исправил ответ. // alias, насколько я понимаю, необходим в обоих случаях. ведь index.php, насколько я понял вопрос, должен вызываться из корня сайта.